# Konica Autoreflex TC lifting mirror on film advance

Tags: mirror, konica

My Konica Autoreflex TC will lift the mirror every time I advance the film.

I can get it to stop every once in a while just for a picture by messing with the lever jiggling it back and forth before I crank it all the way.

I am not trying to do that constantly so please help!!!

Comment: When you jiggle the lever back and forth how do you know when you can crank the lever to advance the film without raising the mirror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera is malfunctioning. Maybe permanently broken. Maybe just in need of repair/servicing.

The Konica Autoreflex TC was an entry level camera and not readily sought after by people today.

This means it probably won't make economic sense to have it repaired or serviced professionally. It probably won't make sense in terms of time either because the few remaining camera repair shops are often backed up with repairs.

Practically speaking, the simplest thing to do is replace it with another used camera. Working examples on US eBay appear to be available (in June 2021) for less than $60 including shipping. This is almost certainly less than any professional repair.

Alternatively, a working entry level used camera of different model and/or make can also be found for similar costs. Probably with lenses if you are patient.

Part of the replacement cost might be offset by selling the current camera for parts.

It might be possible to repair it yourself, depending on the quality of your tools, the condition of your camera, and most importantly your overall camera repair ability. Take a look at the Fix Old Cameras Youtube channel if that idea appeals to you. If you mess it up, you can still probably sell it for parts.

It is hard for some people, including me, to let an old camera go when the economics don't work. But if you only have one camera and it is not working, replacing it is the best way to get back out and make pictures.

And in the end, that is why we care when a camera breaks.